# Only count distinct elements from join in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have those two tables in my database :

```
╔════════════════╗
║ beer           ║
╠════════════════╣
║ id             ║
║ name           ║
║ ...            ║
╚════════════════╝

╔════════════════╗
║ checkin        ║
╠════════════════╣
║ id             ║
║ beer_id        ║
║ user_id        ║
║ date           ║
║ ...            ║
╚════════════════╝
```

I made this simple query which returns the number of times a beer has been checked-in:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) as TOTAL, b.*, c.*
FROM beer b
JOIN checkin c ON c.beer_id = b.id
GROUP BY c.beer_id
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

What would be the best way to modify it so that the "TOTAL" count that is returned is by unique users (if a user has several check-ins of the same beer it should only be counted once) ?

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  All non-aggregated columns must be in `GROUP BY`.  `*` is not permitted in `SELECT` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What is the user column you're trying to `DISTINCT`? Is it `c.id`?

Comment: I have edited the initial question as maybe it wasn't clear enough. I'd like the "TOTAL" count only count checkins from 1 user per beer. Like, if a user has 3 checkins of beer X, and another has 1 checkin of beer X, "TOTAL" for beer X would be 2 instead of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count distinct users by grouping on beerId.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct c.user_id) as TOTAL
FROM beer b
JOIN checkin c ON c.beer_id = b.id
GROUP BY c.beer_id
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: Ah, that's perfect, thank you for fixing my dead brain :)